# How to authenticate an Html + Javascript app with JWT

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, nginx, jwt

I have a front end application written in Html and JavaScript, which is hosted on an nginx server and a back end API. I want to authenticate it.

**In detail**

There are 3 html pages:

1. www.url.com/Items
2. www.url.com/Item
3. www.url.com/Login

And let us say I have an API endpoint ServerIP/Login, which returns a **JWT**.

**The proposed solution**

When the user clicks on www.url.com/Login they are presented with a login form in which they pass their credentials and then a request is made to the api which returns a token, which is stored on the client side.

Then if the user hits on www.url.com/Item or any other page, there should be javascript code to check if a JWT is present. If yes, it should check if it has expired. If yes, it should redirect user to the login page. If no, it will allow the page to load.

**Question**

Is this a valid design? Is there a better way of handling this without having to run server side code such as PHP, nodeJS or JSP ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the fact that your frontend does not contain and secure data in its code then yes.

```
-- User logs in
-- Receive JWT token 
-- Token stored storage 
-- Navigated to items page 
-- Passes the token to the API to get items list 
-- so on and so forth...
```

Do make sure that you have token validation on the server-side for your token. Also, this does pose a risk if the token gets intercepted so make sure you have other forms of validations to ensure where the token is coming from.

Comment: But Items is an html page on nginx. There are no html served from the API.

Comment: No html needs to be transmitted from the API. You can just serve data that your frontend can display. For example, you frontend can request items from the API which in turn returns a JSON of all the items and your frontend (Not sure what you are using for that) can then take that list and display it in a neatly formatted view.

If you are hardcoding your items in the frontend, then you need to validate if your token is valid before even displaying the items page (Not sure how you are displaying data)

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Although I want the whole Items page not to be served, if someone presses on its url.